# CommandFailedException when running Glue ETL Job

Tags: aws-glue

When I try to run my Glue ETL Job, I get the following error:

> CommandFailedException: Script file doesn't exist s3://my-bucket/my-script.py

I double-checked the path, and it is correct. I can see the script source code on the Glue Job in the AWS Console.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message can be caused by an IAM permissions issue. Make sure the IAM role on the Glue Job has a policy that allows it to read from the S3 bucket where the script file is stored. For example:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListObjects"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to s3 my-bucket Bucket policy and add this :

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::account-id:assumed-role/GlueServiceRole/GlueJobRunnerSession"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        ]
    }
```

Also, you can add an identical one for the glue service role